# How I can capture Data from attendance machine

Tags: c#, java, php, time-and-attendance

I have developed an online leave management system in PHP, MySQL, which is working fine, I have only one issue, we have to upload a csv file of daily captured data. I want to do it automatically.

We have a [Star Link Attendance machine](http://www.starlinkindia.com/OurProducts/ClassicModel.aspx).

Star Link software dose not provide any custom report format.

I want to develop an application module which can fetch data from this machine?
Is it possible? and in which language we can do it (PHP, C#, Java) ?

Any resource link will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

All data fetched by machine are stored in mssql database, I simply developed a programme in C# .Net which takes the data from mssql and export it in CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I like Java, but every language is okay, if it has lib- to parse CSV file.
you may using FTP,HTTP to get that file.

Comment: I need to know how to get data out of machine. some code would be very beneficial

Comment: Is there any driver to read/comunicate with that machine? It must have a line to connect to your pc/server to read the data. make a call to StarLink

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://dnaextrim.github.io/php_zklib/) It uses the UDP protocol to communicate to the Attendance Machine.
And [this](http://dnaextrim.github.io/python_zklib/) for Python